# Specifying static and dynamic sizes at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, boost, architecture, software-design

For the moment, I have a class, of the following form:

```
template <std::size_t N, 
          class T,
          class Allocator = typename std::conditional<N, void, std::allocator<T>>::type>
class myclass {};
```

Which is a particular container with the following behaviour:

- if `N > 0`, then the container has a static size of `N`, and the `Allocator` template parameter should be `void`.
- if `N == 0`, then the container is of dynamic size of, and the `Allocator` parameter will be used.

But I am not satisfied with this design because it does not seem elegant. I would like a solution `standard-like` or `boost-ready`. Maybe such a problem has already been encountered for the design of one of the boost libary. If so what solution has been chosen?

Considering the fact that I want to keep a single version of `myclass`, and not two version `static_myclass` and `dynamic_myclass`.

Comment: Does the user may provide `Allocator` or it is just use as internal implementation ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, the user may provide the Allocator.

Comment: What's about removing `N` and create a special "fixed_allocator<N>" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a good use-case for CRTP. Have a base class which does all the important stuff, which asks its derived class for the actual objects:

```
template <typename Derived, typename T>
class myclass_base_impl { 
    // generic stuff
    // static_cast to Derived& to get actual data
};
```

Then, you have two versions of it. The dynamic one:

```
template <typename T>
class myclass_dynamic 
: public myclass_base_impl<myclass_dynamic<T>, T>
{
    /* stuff that uses std::allocator<T> */
};
```

And the static one:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class myclass_static
: public myclass_base_impl<myclass_static<T, N>, T>
{
     // presumably something like
    T data_[N];
};
```

Comment: I agree that this is an elegant solution for implementation. But I was more talking about the user interface. Given for example the fact that I will have 10 classes like myclass. The obvious solution would be to duplicate the interface and make static and dynamic versions. But it become less convenient for example, if some of myclass need two sizes specifications.

Comment: @Vincent I don't understand your comment at all.